# UIView inside a UIButton

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton

I have to add a button. This should be glowing non stop. So I used an external library. By this I have to add the image to an UIImageView and then the imageview to the view. This is added to the button. The glow is enabled by the startGlow: method which takes in a UIView. This forces me to add the UIView to the UIButton. The problem comes in when I touch the button, it is not responsive inside which is filled with UIView. The edges seems to work fine. Any fix for this? I want the button to be responsive for all the TouchInside event. Thank you

Comment: Why can't you pass your button? `UIButton` is a child class of `UIView`.

Comment: The glow effect comes from the edges of the view and the view is square in shape. The image is circular.

Comment: Does your button transparent? Maybe you could place the view under the button on another view? Could you screen a screenshot?

Comment: Troolee.. thanks for the suggestion.. i did the same just now.. it did work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't need to interact with a view you can turn off the interaction by setting the userInteractionEnabled property to NO. You should then be able to interact with the view or UIButton below it.

Comment: Don't you have to set it to YES anyway?

Comment: a UIView pick all events by default so I think setting the property to NO is the right answer here: By doing so the events won't be picked up by the overlay view but by the button below it. Let me know if i am wrong.